# VB.NET Click a checkbox into Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

I have a DatagridView with data directly from a recordset.

I had a new column before the others as a checkbox type with this code:

```
Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
gridRicette.Columns.Add(chk)
chk.HeaderText = "Sel."
chk.Name = "chk"
```

And it appear. But when I click on the the checkbox, nothing happens.

Can you help me to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to bind it to the correct column on your data source. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.binding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I done it, but when I click on the checkbox I'm not "enable" to check/uncheck it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this....

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim chk As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    gridRicette.Columns.Add(chk)
    chk.HeaderText = "Sel."
    chk.Name = "chk"
End Sub

Private Sub gridRicette_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles gridRicette.CellContentClick
    Dim senderGrid As DataGridView = sender
    Dim data = senderGrid.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem

    If senderGrid.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).GetType() Is GetType(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn) And e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("You selected row {0}", e.RowIndex))
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

You can use the DataGridView1_CellContentClick event and then determine what has been clicked by the user.... hope that helps.